# How to find out code creating garbage objects

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

Application is creating 3GB of garbage objects and this gets garbage collected.  This process of creating garbage and it's subsequent collection repeats every 30 mins.  I took heap dump and could identify Unreachable Objects but there is no way to identify code creating these UnReachable objects.   Please let me know if there is a way to find out code responsible for this without buying Jprofiler / YourKit.

Comment: What seems to be a problem? What's wrong with garbage being collected?

Comment: This process of creating 3GB garbage and its collection repeats every 30 mins.  Memory graph is full of densely packed mountains. I would like this to be very sparse, with less frequency of GC and less creation of garbage. Hence, need to know which part of code is creating garbage

Comment: Do you know what the objects are?  if you do, look for something creating them and then freeing the references.  GC is normal part of Java programming. now if you are holding things for to short a period of time and should be caching them to avoid extra garbage that is an architectural decision in you app.

Comment: I understand this and not worried about objects for which i am holding references as these are architectural decisions. Finding out reference of garbage in code and then deducting is herculean task

Comment: Try [aprof](https://code.devexperts.com/display/AProf/About+Aprof) - allocation profiler.

Answer (score 1):

You can always Java Flight recorder and Java Mission Control instead of Jprofiler/YourKit. It is supported from version  Oracle JDK 7 Update 40 (7u40) onwards. Unless you are not on versions lower than this.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc.htm

Comment: Yes , i am using java 7 update 51. Isnt  flight recorder commercial feature ?

Comment: Look at the Licensing section in the below URL. http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/10/misson-control-flight-recorder. There is no specific check I believe. I remember using it sometime back to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

You might try taking a heap dump and feeding it to the Memory Analysis Tool:
https://eclipse.org/mat/
It should give you some ideas of what you have a lot of and possibly where they came from.

Comment: Tried that.  Heap dump helps in finding out Unreachable / garbage objects but not their call hierarchy. JDK 7 flight recorder helped me a lot.